# Intellj shows a breakpoint is invalid for a jar file I import, anyone know how to make it valid?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Intellj shows a breakpoint is invalid.
I want to debug into a jar file I include in my project.

Comment: which version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: This usually happens when the source is out of sync with compiled code. Does the jar contain source ?

Comment: I don't find this question unclear at all. OP wants to breakpoint on decompiled code in his IDE and is asking how to do it. I don't see how much more clear can you make it.

Answer (score 2):

With Intellij pre 14.1 you would have to attach a source file of that project, you cannot simply debug a decompiled jar. I'm assuming you are using an older version of Intellij so you have two options:

- attach the source code of that jar (Project Structure -> Attach Sources)
- upgrade to version 14.1, then you can use your breakpoints as usual without attaching the source code